# Some usernames overflow in chat

Tags: bug, chat, display-names

Screenshot shows everything:

[image]

[That user's](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/107245/undergroundmonorail) name is *"undergroundmonorail"* and it overflows. I've also noticed this for another user.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call their usernames "bugs", but they could indeed make them shorter. :p

Comment: It should `...` them.

Comment: [Another overflow](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7MM1C.jpg)